# Android: Use RTL LayoutDirection On api lower than 17

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this code for rtl layoutDirection for actionBar:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(
                    View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

and this on manifest:

```
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

but it's not working on android 4.1.2 or lower.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: layout direction was added in API 17 and therefore cannot be used on versions < 17.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2